# How do i count number of consultated

Tags: sql, oracle

/*16 Write a query to show the Staff Id, number of consultations. Name the new column Num of Consults.*/

```
COLUMN COUNT(dateconsulted) HEADING "Num of Consults"
SELECT staffid,
       COUNT(dateconsulted)
FROM consultation;
```

> ERROR at line 1: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

it should count how many number of consults that has been completed

Edited i got it to work i hope but the next one is similar

/* Write a query to show the Staff id, number of consultations only for staff that have more than 2 consulation Name the new column Num of Consults
*/
/*come back to this double checking after */

COLUMN COUNT(*) HEADING "Num of Consults"
SELECT staffid,
        COUNT(*)
FROM consultation
WHERE 'Num of Consults'> 2
GROUP BY staffid;

Result that i wanting is to just disply the Num Of consults that is greater > than 2 but for some reason it keep other record when i want to display just the record of more than 2

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: For aggregation functions we use `HAVING` in the `GROUP BY` clause not `WHERE`. [Find out more](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
SELECT 
     staffid, COUNT(dateconsulted) as "Num of Consults"
FROM consultation
    GROUP BY staffid;
```

Comment: that does work but the result not counting how many time that the consultation that the staff have done  ST Num of Consults
-- ---------------
3                1
7                1
12               1
1                1

Comment: @MarcusWilliamDavis : [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55447875/edit) your question and add some sample rows and expected output and tell us what's not working